# How to Use "php" on Azure App Service Website

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to add a "php" based "info request" email function to an Azure based website page's form. Is there something necessary to be setup to enable "php" to be executed on the app service's website?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just make sure you'll select php on Stack Settings

[image]